# Adding Referrer Code to Link

Tags: jquery

I have a site and I want to add following code to all specific urls.

> ?site=Mysite.com

Sample :

> targetsite.com/fileID/filename.rar

Result :

> targetsite.com/fileID/filename.rar?site=Mysite.com

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: Nothing, because I dont know what I can do. I looked some examples but I didnt find same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this js code.
I used [attribute contains selector (href*)](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to find href's with 'targetsite.com' string.

```js
$("a[href*='targetsite.com']").attr('href', function() { return this+'?site=Mysite.com' });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://targetsite.com">Test1</a>
<a href="targetsite.com/test">Test1</a>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much. That is it what I want. Can you please write here full codes? Thanks you again!